# I want to return the true value when the month picker is selected, but there is a problem, so it keeps returning the false value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a month picker like the picture below. I erased the code, leaving only the part to ask questions. When the month picker is rendered for the first time, there is no selected value, and if I select month, the value comes out. I want to return false when nothing is selected at first and return true when month is selected. So I checked the value with `console.log(`pickMonth:`,pickMonth==="")`, and when it was rendered for the first time, true came out and false returned if there was a value. So I typed `console.log(`pickMonth:`,pickMonth===!"")` because I needed the opposite value. But whether there is a value or not, it keeps returning false. What's wrong? I'd appreciate it if you let me know thanks.

[image]

**code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Cake from '../resources/images/img/cake.png'
import DownArrow from '../resources/images/img/downarrow.png'



const BirthdayWrap = styled.div`
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
`

function Birthday() {
  
  const [pickMonth,setPickMonth] = useState('');
  const handleSelectMonth = (e) => {
    setPickMonth(e.target.value)
  }

  console.log(`pickMonth:`, pickMonth==='')
  console.log(`pickMonth value:`, pickMonth)

 
  return (
    <BirthdayWrap isLoginGood={isLoginGood} pickMonth={pickMonth} pickDay={pickDay} pickYear={pickYear}>
      <div>
        <span>
          <img alt='cake' src={Cake} />
        </span>
        <div>
            <div>
              <span>
                <span>
                  <img alt='arrow' src={DownArrow} />
                </span>
                <select value={pickMonth} onChange={handleSelectMonth}>
                  <option className='monthOption' value="1">
                    Jan
                  </option>
                  <option className='monthOption' value="2">
                    Feb
                  </option>
                  <option className='monthOption' value="3">
                    March
                  </option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <span>
                <span>
                  <img alt='arrow' src={DownArrow} />
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BirthdayWrap>
  )
}

export default Birthday;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have to use a double bang on `pickMonth` instead of doing a comparison operator. Empty strings are inferred as falsey.

```js
let pickMonth = ''
console.log(`pickMonth: `, !!pickMonth) // pickMonth: false

let pickMonth = 'foo'
console.log(`pickMonth: `, !!pickMonth) // pickMonth: true
```

Comment: Also if you really want to use a comparison operator you need to move your bang. Like this `console.log("pickMonth:", pickMonth !== '')`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know, but now I know. The cord works fine, too!